# Getting local timezone identifier when OS display language is non-english

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

Strangely, `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName` returns localized name as per computer display language. I want a programmatic identifier that I can provide to `TimeZoneInfo` in following code.

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
```

`FindSystemTimeZoneById` expects a unique un-localized programmatic identifier

I changed my computer display language to Chinese and I was getting a localized unicode string when I do `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName`.  However the value was correct but it was localized in computer display language which is something I do not want.

I do not have option of using `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` right now because my project is in .Net 2.0.  What other options do I have to get un-localized timezone identifier?

Answer (score 2):

To get the equivalent of `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` without being able to use the `TimeZoneInfo` class, you will have to go directly to the registry.

In .NET 2.0 C#, you can retrieve it with the following method:

```
private static string GetLocalTimeZoneId()
{
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                        @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation");
    string value = (string)key.GetValue("TimeZoneKeyName");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        value = (string)key.GetValue("StandardName");
    key.Close();
    return value;
}
```

Windows Vista and greater have the `TimeZoneKeyName` value, and have a `@tzres.dll` pointer entry in the `StandardName` value.

Before Windows Vista, the `StandardName` value contained the key name, and was not localized.

The above code accounts for both variations.

Comment: Thanks Matt. That's the answer I was looking for!  Now my only worry is does that registry path remain same for all flavor of Windows?

Comment: I'm getting really strange results when I try to use this. The registry entry looks correct in RegEdit, but when I read it with key.GetValue("TimeZoneKeyName") what I get back is a boxed string containing 127 characters. The first characters are the name of the time zone, followed by a couple of hex 00 characters ("\0\0"), followed by stuff that looks like random garbage. I can, of course, extract the name myself via IndexOf('\0'), but why is key.GetValue() returning the garbage characters as well as the correct data?

Comment: Maybe what I'm getting is related to this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eca7ad76-c910-46be-8fb9-876c7cde5c69/registry-read-time-zone-info-differ-when-code-build-on-40-framework-on-host-system-win-7-64-bit?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Strange.  What OS version?

Comment: I've posted this as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716746/hklm-system-currentcontrolset-control-timezoneinformation-timezonekeyname-corrup Would greatly appreciate it if you took a look at it. And thanks for this answer.